# How to divide a grid in ListView, in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp

```
<Grid Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ListView x:Name="lvAlert" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="{Binding ColorValue }" >
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AlertType}" Foreground="White"  Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="1"  Background="{Binding ColorValue }" >
                                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding AlertTypeValue}" Foreground="Black" Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding AlertType}" Foreground="{Binding ColorValue }"  Width="400" Height="40"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding AlertTypeValue}" Foreground="{Binding ColorValue }" Width="400" Height="40"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
```

When I run the above code I got an output as in a single line without getting properly separation in 70% and 30%. Can anyone solve this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, ListView's items don't stretch horizontally, but stick to the left.

Your problem should be solved by this code:

```
 <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
       <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
               Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
 </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I run the above code I got an output as in a single line without getting properly separation in 70% and 30%. Can anyone solve this?

It's because the `Height` of `ColumnDefinitions` should be set `7*` and `3*` instead of `70*` and `30*`:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

For details of Grid usage, you can refer to [Gird Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.aspx).